# `a4j:support` doesn't call action in Chrome https. (only)

Tags: jsp, jsf, richfaces

Got this little segment of JSP code:

```
<h:commandLink value="#{msg.Submit_Button}">
    <a4j:support event="onclick" reRender="rerenderObject" 
                 action="#{general.submit}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

When I click the link it works in http for all browsers.
It works in https for IE and firefox (Tested) but not for chrome. 
The method doesn't get called in chrome in https.

Any Idea Why?

Thanks!

**UPDATE (More info):**

The first one doesn't work. The second one does. (first is ajax second isn't)

```
<h:commandLink value="AJAX STYLE"  style="margin: 4px" >
    <a4j:support event="onclick" action="#{general.submit}" />
</h:commandLink>
<h:commandLink value="NON-AJAX"  style="margin: 4px" action="#{general.submit}" >
```

Also, apparently this doesn't occur when run on localhost (server and client same machine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just use a4j:commandButton instead of adding a4j:support to a standard button.

Answer (score 0):

I think i have the answer - 
When I change from `h:commandLink` to `h:outputText` it seems to work.
I guess `h:commandLink` overrides the `onclick` event for `a4j:support` (Although I assumed it would be the other way around)

And the strange thing is, it happends only in chrome and from a different host.
Wierd...
If someone can explain this I'll mark his answer as the official answer.